# How can I input this C++ code in Dart

Tags: c++, dart

I have to make this C++ code in Dart, but I find it really difficult. I tryed watching Darts video and searching on the web, but with no success.Could someone be able to give me a hand?
This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n < 0) return 1;
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= n) sum += i*i;
    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to change the loop to `while (i <= n) { sum += i*i; i++}` to avoid the infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

something like

```dart
library x;

import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) {
  int n;
  print('input a number');
  String input = stdin.readLineSync();
  n = int.parse(input);
  print('n: $n');
  if(n < 0) {
    exit(1);
  }

  int sum = 0;
  int i = 0;

  while(i <= n) {
    print(sum);
    sum += i * i;
  }

  print(sum);
}
```

But don't expect to much.
When reaching the while loop `sum` and `i` are 0. 
This way you have produced a nice endless loop to busy your computer ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much Gunter! I would never be able to it alone. Again, thank you very very much for your help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do the calculation bit (sum of squares of all numbers from 1 to n inclusive) with a recursive function like:

```
int recur(int n) => (n > 0) ? (n * n) + recur(n - 1) : 0;
```

Then it's a simple matter of figuring out how to enter `n` and output `recur(n)`. That can be done with `stdin.readLineSync` and `print`. That would be along the following lines:

```
int recur(int n) => (n > 0) ? (n * n) + recur(n - 1) : 0;

void main( List<String> args ) {
    int inNum;
    String input = stdin.readLineSync();
    inNum = int.parse( input );
    if (inNum < 0) {
        exit( 1 );
    }
    print( recur( sum ) );
}
```

Just be careful with large input values, I'm not sure whether Dart is smart enough to do tail end recursion optimisation. If not, stack space may be an issue.